# No Iceland visa appointments in London

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, iceland

According to the current rules, vaccinated travellers are allowed in Iceland.

I am an Indian passport holder with a Tier 2 visa in the UK. I need a Schengen visa to visit Iceland but the VFS website says there are no appointments available. Is there a specific time when appointments become available?
What are my options?

[image]

Comment: Have you asked VFS Global?

Comment: According to https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/iceland-visa/uk/, 'in the United Kingdom, Schengen visas for Iceland are arranged through the Embassy of Denmark'. My search brings me to https://applyvisa.um.dk/NVP.App/frontpage. Have you tried it out?

Comment: Yep, asked VFS Global: they don't know when appointments will be available.
Also, tried the Denmark embassy: can't create an account there because I don't get a confirmation email

Tldr: Both suggestions above didn't work :/